# How to calculate numbers using international numeral systems in JavaScript/jQuery and HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

If you are calculating two numbers that use the notation of another numeral system, how do you convert the numbers so they can be used in calculations?

Comment: Did you answer your question the same minute you answered it? Indeed more open knowledge is always better.

Comment: Yes I did! And I love open knowledge. Answering QA style is an option in SO after you reach 100 rep points, and this was something I figured out working on an unrelated question, so moved it here so folks could find it better if they were looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using Globalize.js to Allow International Number Formatting

jQuery offers a script developed with Microsoft called [globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) that formats numbers based on a locale. In [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/3JqVk/13/), I used Spain as the locale as an example, but its capable of many more formats and locales. Try using notation like 1.234,56 to check calculations. You can use the toLocaleString() function to format the calculated number back to a localized format, but this currently only works in Chrome and IE. You could use [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) for the other browsers, but this is all I had time for. Here is the basic script, but look at [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/3JqVk/13/) to see the other js required and the changes that needed to be made to the form tags.

```
<script>
    function Sumar() {
        var num1 = Globalize.parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtNumber1").value);
        var num2 = Globalize.parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtNumber2").value);
        resultado = num1 + num2;
        document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "The result is " + resultado.toLocaleString("es-ES");
    }
</script>
```